# How to save only last message from topic to a file?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

As in the title - how to save only last message from topic to a file? I've tried to do this but when I open a file it contains about last 10 message that I've send before. Here is my code:

```
public class Consumer {
FileWriter fw;
PrintWriter pw;

public void Consume(String topic){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "ranking_consumer");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topic));

    File dir = new File("C:/kafka-logs/kafka-logs-0/data");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
    }

    try{
    while(true){
        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(1000);
        int chunkSize = records.count();
        int recordIndex = 0;

        for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records){
            recordIndex++;
            if (recordIndex == chunkSize){
            fw = new FileWriter("C:/kafka-logs/kafka-logs-0/data/msg-"+topic, false);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            pw.print(record.value());
            pw.close();
            }
        }
    }} catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
    consumer.close();
    }
}
```

}

**NOTE:** Added the lines of code proposed by dbustosp

**NOTE2:** To explain more clearly my problem. I have a simple JFrame for producer with "choose file" button which send .csv file as a string variable. Then I have a second simple JFrame for receiving the last published message and save it to the file. Maybe I have a bad declaration of thread for consumer but when I send a couple of messages from producer I receive a file with a few of the same messages instead of only one - the last. Below I send my code for consumer's JFrame and producer:

```
public class Producer {

public void Produce(String msg, String topic){

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("acks", "all");
    props.put("retries", 0);
    props.put("batch.size", 16384);
    props.put("linger.ms", 1);
    props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, msg);
    producer.send(record);
    producer.close();
}
}

public class Kafka_Consumer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Thread t;

public Kafka_Consumer() {
    initComponents();
}
private void btn_ReceiveFromKafkaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    if (textField_topic.getText().equals("")) {
        showMessageDialog(null, "Nie wprowadziłeś/aś tematu!");
    }
    else{
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
        t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
        consumer.Consume(textField_topic.getText());
        }
    });
    t.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you notice that you are creating a new Consumer every time you passed through the 'else' clause. Also, a new Thread is also initialized and executed. You are not stopping the threads at all. The problem that you have is around how you are handling the Consumers and Threads. You can start a new question around this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any code handling the last message after a poll request. 
With the following modification in your code should work.

```
// Getting the chunk size got from poll
int chunkSize = records.count();
// Index to count the number of the message
int recordIndex = 0;
for(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
    // Increasing to count the number of message visited
    recordIndex++;
    // Checking the last message
    if (recordIndex == size) {
        fw = new FileWriter("C:/kafka-logs/kafka-logs-0/data/msg-"+topic, false);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.print(record.value());
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked the first time but when I added several messages, there are still a few of the same messages

Comment: That piece of code is picking the last record in the chunk you are bringing from the poll request, I do not see any reason why would not be doing the work that you wanted originally. Would be great if you can add more details about what are you expecting to see and what is the data is already in the queue and if there is any process pushing data into the Topic/Partition which you are consuming.

Comment: Added Note2 for better explanation